# stopping block comments from creating a * on every new line

Tags: phpstorm

i hate this with a passion, problem is that i can't seem to find any setting that allows me to remove it, on the phpstorm site they says that to create a comment block you use /** but i know that's a load of crap cause i've been creating them with /* and deleting the new * created but this ruins the auto indenting phpstrom does

so is there a way to prevent phpstorm from adding a * on every new line when you create a comment block, i'm only looking to do this for PHP since it's the language i'm normally coding in which i need to make block comments for functions and files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a line with /* the IDE is trying to be helpful with adding the *s.

Instead you can block comment the code with keyboard shortcuts:

[image: Comments]

Comment: kinda useless when my block comments contains multiple lines, ones that i have at the top of files have version history and for functions have a list of arguments, putting // on every new line is more annoying than removing a * and it still breaks the auto indenting

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: oh that.....i guess that's a good enough alternative, that's what i sued to do in Visual Studio (but it wasn't a keyboard shortcut), i just need to know remember to do that after i finish typing